# Laravel 5 logs - Apache vs CLI conflict

Tags: php, laravel

By default Laravel saves daily log files in `storage/logs` with 644 permissions. That creates a problem when the first log entry is written by Apache and then PHP run from CLI tries to write something (or the other way around). If I run `ls -lh storage/logs/` the results look something like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 test.example.org test.example.org 36K Jun 15 10:07 laravel-2015-06-15.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data         www-data         24K Jun 16 09:55 laravel-2015-06-16.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data         www-data         254 Jun 17 12:11 laravel-2015-06-17.log
```

So the first user to write the log file on a given day will be the only one to be able to write it for the rest of the day.

Is it possible to make Laravel save the logs with 666 permission? The solutions to this problem that I found suggest running `sudo chmod -R 666 storage/logs`, but that doesn't really solve the problem - Laravel will keep creating files with 644 mask in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was finally able to sort it out. Quite a lot of extending was necessary, but I didn't need to edit any vendor files, which is good. So, here it goes:

New file `app/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php`:

```
    namespace App\Bootstrap;

    use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
    use App\Support\Log\Writer;
    use Monolog\Logger as Monolog;

    class ConfigureLogging extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging {

        protected function configureDailyWithChmodHandler(Application $app, Writer $log)
        {
            $log->useDailyFilesWithChmod(
                $app->storagePath().'/logs/laravel.log',
                $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5)
                );
        }

        protected function registerLogger(Application $app)
        {
            $app->instance('log', $log = new Writer(
                new Monolog($app->environment()), $app['events'])
            );

            return $log;
        }

    }
```

In `app/Console/Kernel.php` I've added to top:

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
```

and then I've added this constructor:

```
    public function __construct(Application $app, Dispatcher $events)
    {
            $idx = array_search('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', $this->bootstrappers);
            if ($idx) {
                    array_splice($this->bootstrappers, $idx, 1, 'App\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging');
            }
            parent::__construct($app, $events);
    }
```

Similar changes have to be done in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
    use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
    ...
    public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
    {
            $idx = array_search('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', $this->bootstrappers);
            if ($idx) {
                    array_splice($this->bootstrappers, $idx, 1, 'App\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging');
            }
            parent::__construct($app, $router);
    }
```

Then `app/Support/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php`:

```
    namespace App\Support\Handler;

    class RotatingFileHandler extends \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler{

           protected function write(array $record)
           {
                   parent::write($record);
                   if ($this->mustRotate) {
                           chmod($this->url, 0666);
                   }
           }

    }
```

Also `app/Support/Log/Writer.php`:

```
    namespace App\Support\Log;

    use App\Support\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;

    class Writer extends \Illuminate\Log\Writer{
           public function useDailyFilesWithChmod($path, $days = 0, $level = 'debug')
           {
                   $this->monolog->pushHandler(
                           $handler = new RotatingFileHandler($path, $days, $this->parseLevel($level))
                   );

                   $handler->setFormatter($this->getDefaultFormatter());
           }
    }
```

And finally replace the "log" option in `config/app.php`:

```
    'log' => 'dailyWithChmod'
```

You'll probably need to run `composer dump-autoload` so that new classes are found.

If you have any problems and Laravel is displaying no errors, adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to your Kernel should help.